# With Ipython.parallel, How could i monitor the progress of a task?

Tags: parallel-processing, monitoring, ipython

Something like this would be nice :

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
dv=Client()[0]

import time
def waitprogress(n):
  for i in range(n):
    time.sleep(1)
    global progress
    progress=str(i)+'/'+str(n)

dv.block=False
dv.apply(waitprogress,10)

dv['progress']
# the command wait 10 seconds, then returns 9/10
```

This does'nt work because IPython wait the dv.apply to end before searching for the progress variable in the remote instance.

Any idea great people of SO ?

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of SO : [Reading the stdout of ipcluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823548/reading-the-stdout-from-slave-nodes-with-ipcluster?rq=1)
I found out a solution using stdout :

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
c=Client()
dv=c[0]

import time
def waitprogress(n):
  for i in range(n):
    time.sleep(1)
    print str(i)+'/'+str(n)

dv.block=False
res=dv.apply(waitprogress,10)

print c.spin() or c.metadata[res.msg_ids[0]].stdout.split()[-1]
#1/10
time.sleep(3)
print c.spin() or c.metadata[res.msg_ids[0]].stdout.split()[-1]
#4/10
```

If someone has a better solution, would be great